# Vi Keybindings in DrRacket

Tags: vim, scheme, key-bindings, racket

Has anyone got any idea if drracket editor has got vi keybindings or if there is a plugin for that can activate vi keybindings within drracket?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is another pacakge for vim-like bindings: https://github.com/takikawa/drracket-vim-tool